# Google Maps For Android not showing Metro Stations and other Public Places

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-maps

I have successfully plotted a line between some random co-ordinates on Google Maps for Android. But as I can see Public places such as Transport utilities (Metro stations) and other important roads are not being displayed. Now to add to this problem I got confused when I read  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328959/choosing-right-approch-to-implement-google-map-in-android). 
So, I guess that I am probably using Native SDK's Google Maps (importing `com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;` and have mentioned `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` in the Application's Manifest file) that too I am testing my app on Android v.2.3.3 (both on emulator and on HTC Desire S with 2.3.3).

Do I have to set any Map View flags in the MapView Controller to display the important roads, public utilities etc? What am I missing? Any advice will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nvm guys..I have been passing wrong co-ordinates.

Actually not completely wrong, but the format in which they were passed was wrong.

`28°28'46"N (Lat) 77°4'47"E (Lon)` is same as `28.4795 (Lat) 77.0800 (Lon)`
But not 28.2846 77.0447 

:)